# For every integer $n$, the remainder when $n^4$ is divided by $8$ is either $0$ or $1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> For every integer $n$, the remainder when $n^4$ is divided by $8$ is either $0$ or $1$.

So far I have figured out that $n^4 = 8m$ or $n^4 = 8m + 1$.
Any help or hints are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You've almost got it! Try to divide those two numbers you wrote down by $8$. In the first case, what's the remainder? In the second, what's the remainder?

Comment: You seem to be there.  What is the remainder of $8m$ (or $8m+1$) when divided by 8?

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys! So going off of your hints I can see that if I divide the first case by 8, I get a remainder of zero, and if I divide the second case by 8, I get a remainder of one. However, how does this help me prove the statement because I just went in a circle in my reasoning (A is B because B is A)?

Comment: I edited the tags on the question to help put it with related questions.

Answer (score 3):

For odd $n$, let $n=2m+1$

$\displaystyle\implies n^2=(2m+1)^2=8\frac{m(m+1)}2+1=8b+1$ where $b=\frac{m(m+1)}2$ is an integer

$\displaystyle\implies n^4=(8b+1)^2=64b^2+16b+1$

The even case is ease enough

Comment: Thank you! I fully understand your reasoning!

Comment: @wonggr, observe that the divisor can be $16$ as well

Comment: I know it's been a while, but an interesting follow up exercise to this: find all natural numbers $n_{1} \leq ..... \leq n_{14}$ s.t $n_{1}^{4}+...+n_{14}^{4} = 1599$. Hint: you have to use the proven equation but with 16.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $n=8k+r \to n^4=8A+r^4$ and note that $0\leq r<8$

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is by using the powerful tool "$mod\ 8$"  for any $ n \in \mathbb{N}: n \equiv 0,1, 2, 3 ,4 , 5 , 6 \ or\   7 \ mod\ 8 \equiv 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -3, -2 \ or\    -1 \ mod \ 8$

so for ${n^4}$ we have

${n^4}={n^2}^2 = n^3 n \equiv 0^4, 1^4, 2^3 \times 2 , {3^2}^2, {4^2}^2, {-3^2}^2, -2^3 \times 2 \ or\    -1^4 \ mod \ 8 \equiv 0, 1, 0, 1,0,1,0,1 \ mod\ 8 $

I hope I didn't make it more complicated .