# Proofs related with odd numbers and modulo 8

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

In my problem I have

$ s! + s^{2P} \equiv 1 \mod  8$

where $s > 4, P \geq 1, s,P \in  \mathbb{Z}^+$

I tried to follow that example's logic, but I could not get a result

$n^2 \equiv 1 \mod 8$

How  can I approach to the solution of this problem?

Comment: If $s$ is odd, find http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571936/for-every-integer-n-the-remainder-when-n4-is-divided-by-8-is-either-0

Comment: Ok. but what about s! ?

Comment: $8$ divides $s!$ for $s\ge?$

Comment: I guess I should also prove that n! ≡ 0 (mod 8)

Comment: $8$ divides $n!\iff n!\equiv0\pmod8$

Comment: 1. You haven't stated what the problem is. 2. The title mentions odd numbers, but the body doesn't. 3. "I tried to follow that example's logic" --- what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if $s \ge 4$, then $s!=1\cdot\color{green}2\cdot3\cdot\color{green}4\cdot...$ is divisible by $\color{green}8$, so $s!\equiv0 \pmod 8$.

Second, by [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), $s^{\phi(8)}=s^4\equiv 1 \pmod 8$. So if $P>2$ we can put $s^{2p}=s^4s^{2(p-2)}\equiv s^{2(p-2)} \pmod 8$ to get same results, so assume $p \le2$ (or look on $p \mod 2$). That means P is either 1 or 2.

$P=1:$
We need to solve $s^2\equiv 1 \pmod8$. Handly solved to get $s=\{1,3,5,7\}$

$P=2$ : The equation $s^4\equiv 1$. This must be true for any $s$ if s and 8 are relative primes, by Euler's theorem.